# Subscribe contacts to newsletter in bulk

Tags: groups, newsletter, subscribe

We've been using a separate tool for newsletters, but I'd like to move those subscriptions into Civi - basically, add users to a mailing group in bulk. There are several thousand of them. I'd prefer not to send them all an opt-in link since they already opted in to the existing newsletter.

What's the best way to accomplish this? All the contacts are already in Civi. I can grab a list of the contact IDs, so I think I could probably handle this just on the database side, but I feel like using the API or SearchKit might be a better approach... I just am not sure how to actually *do* that.

Comment: Could you jjust turn off the confirmation setting, add them, then turn it back on?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that was an option, but I see it now.
My question was really more about how to select and add the users to a group - sorry if that wasn't clear! The criteria for adding the users isn't something available in Civi, it is external data. Through an sql query, I can match up all or almost all of them to contact IDs, but I'm not sure how to bulk add users to a group from a list of contact IDs.

Comment: A bad (as in easy but technically a bit obtuse) option would be to just grab the IDs, the re-import the Contact ID - and add them to a Group via the setting in the Import Wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with Search Builder by making use of the ‘In’ operator and comma separating the IDs.

From the CiviCRM menu - Search > Search Builder or /civicrm/contact/search/builder?reset=1

[image: Search Builder Criteria]

From the results, you can add to group from the actions drop down menu -

[image: Search Builder results]

Comment: Awesome, that works exactly how I wanted it to! Is this functionality in SearchKit? I poked around at it, but I don't see the "In" operator.